# Problems using Bluetooth HID Proxy mode Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, hci

I have a Logitech(branded as Dell) Bluetooth keyboard, mouse and receiver dongle. I usually leave them in HID proxy mode as it means I can just change the dongle between different machines without having to re-pair the keyboard and mouse every time. This worked fine across all devices I tested it on.

I have just updated a machine to Ubuntu 15.10 and when I plug in the dongle, It recognises it as HCI and uses it as a receiver instead of as a proxy. When this machine was running 15.04, it worked as a proxy fine. To activate the dongle as HCI on 15.04, I used to have to plug it in whilst holding down it's button. Doing this on 15.10 does not seem to have any effect as it is already in HCI mode.

Running `lsusb` in either version of Ubuntu lists both an HCI and HID proxy device. Using the dongle on other machines(although I don't have any other 15.10 machines to test on) works as the HID proxy straight up.

Any ideas of how I could force Ubuntu to use it as an HID proxy?

(Also if someone higher-up could create the ubuntu-15.10 tag; I don't have enough rep.)

Comment: Same here. Managed to get mouse working in BT mode but keyboard wont connect.

Comment: No DenverCoder9... what did you see! https://xkcd.com/979/ looking for a solution in Ubuntu 16.04 myself Logitech MX 5500 revolution keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to comment out the Logitech rules as follows. Essentially, Udev is switching the USB adapter from Hid-Proxy to HCI (bluetooth) mode... even with Bluetooth driver disabled.

`/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules`

```
# Logitech devices
#KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
#  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

Reboot and do basic pairing (red button on keyboard then red button on adapter).

I originally used a Windows PC with SetPoint's "Bluetooth Connection Assistant" tool, despite its name, helps pair in HID-Proxy mode, but as soon as this adapter plugged into my Linux box, it was pooched.